# Why isn't Apache NiFi's ValidateRecord catching invalid enums?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to get the Avro Schema Registry to enforce an `enum` type. Here is the relevant part of my avro schema:

```
...
{
  "name": "profileImageSource",
  "type": {
    "name": "ProfileImageSource",
    "type": "enum",
    "symbols" :  ["BASE64", "URL", "S3"]
  },
  "doc": "One of three options as to how the profile image will be provided: BASE64, URL, or S3."
},
...
```

... but, when I use ValidateRecord it ... doesn't -- I can put anything for the `profileImageSource` field, and it is accepted.

**Update (extra info)**

`Strict Type Checking` has no effect (same result regardless of true/false).

If you want to reproduce this, you can use this avro schema and sample data:

**Schema**

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "CustomerRecord",
  "fields": [{
      "name": "identifier",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "profileImageSource",
      "type": {
        "name": "ProfileImageSource",
        "type": "enum",
        "symbols" :  ["BASE64", "URL", "S3"]
      },
      "doc": "One of three options as to how the profile image will be provided: BASE64, URL, or S3."
    },
    {
      "name": "profileImageData",
      "type": "string",
      "doc": "A profile image of the customer."
    }
  ]
}
```

**Data**

```
{
  "identifier": "CUSTOMER-UNO",
  "profileImageSource": "Cheese",
  "profileImageData": "https://google.com"
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Is *Strict Type Checking* set to `true` or `false` in your processor configuration? Can you share more information (relevant configuration, sample input, etc.)?

Comment: @Andy Added more info